# Suggestion on AWS Component & Deployment process

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

Am planning to have multiple restful services (microservices) deployed in AWS. What are the essential components in AWS needed in order to deploy them and how can the deployment be scripted? Am checking on among the below two approaches as to which suite the best.

Approach 1: 
   Create the webservice as a Spring Boot application packaged as jar and deploy in AWS.

Approach 2: 
   Create the webservice as a Spring Boot application packaged as war and deploy to an application server in AWS.

The requirement is part of developing an enterprise application in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to probably Dokerize your Microservices. Springboot comes with default Tomcat server, you can either use it or use undertow.

Once the Microservices are Dockerized, you can either use Docker Hub or Docker Trusted Registry or (any other tool of your choice) to save the Microservices Images.

The microservices Images can deployed in different Virtual Machines in a Cloud Environment (AWS/Azure/Any) using orchestration tools such DC/OS, Docker Data Center, Rancher, etc. If you're still planning to use your microservices like the way Monolith applications work then it will defeat the whole purpose of Microservices.

There are plenty of tools available to automate your continuous deployment. The right place to start is to try out different tools and analyze the pros/cons and come to a conclusion that fits best for you.

Please refer below for a head start:
http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/webinar-enabling-microservices-with-containers-orchestration-and-mongodb